# Bluetooth Programming on Jailbroken iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, bluetooth, jailbreak

I have written a code that transfers the data from one i-Device to another i-Device, but since Apple is coming with official unlocked devices, I want to extend the solution to transfer data from an i-Device to another platform based device.

What changes it will require? How to write this code?
Is there any reference that I can use?

Comment: About which BT profile are you talking exactly? Some of this stuff is under MFi NDA...

Comment: I am talking about cross-platform mobile data transfer. Say from iPhone to android....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously you can not use the Game kit to communicate with a non-iOS devices.
You would have 2 options:

1 - Enroll the "[Made for iPhone](https://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/)" program which allows you to create your own communication protocol, but I think you can not use bt profile for data exchange(like png,mp3..), this program is related to the development of external accessories like bt headsets etc. In this case you have to use [EA Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/ExternalAccessory/Reference/ExternalAccessoryFrameworkReference/_index.html).

2 - If you want to develop apps for jailbroken devices, you can look at [BTStack](http://code.google.com/p/btstack/wiki/iPhoneBluetooth).

Comment: True. iOS device (in best case) supports only these BT profiles: HFP 1.5,PBAP,A2DP,AVRCP,PAN,HID source: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3647